# Using chrome.runtime.sendmessage to communicate from a webpage to a packaged app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to communicate from a web page to a packaged app.  The idea is to have the web page read a number from a serial device.  Because I want to access the serial device, I need a packaged app and can't use an extension.  This is pretty similar to [Keep Chrome Packaged App running in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23267967/1797331) and it seems that [Chrome documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external-webpage) says this is possible.

How can I execute the chrome.runtime.sendMessage from a regular web page?  When I do so, I get *Uncaught TypeError:  Cannot read property 'sendMessage' of undefined.  My simple function is:

```
function doFunction(){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, {openUrlInEditor: url},
      function(response) {
        if (!response.success)
          handleError(url);
      });
}
```

My packaged app loads and can access the serial ports.  But my suspicion is the manifest isn't  "enabling" the chrome.runtime of the regular webpage.  Manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Hello World!",
  "description": "My first Chrome App.",
  "version": "0.1",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": { "16": "calculator-16.png", "128": "calculator-128.png" },
  "permissions": [
    "serial",
    "*://localhost/*"
  ],
  "externally_connectable": {
  "matches": [
      "*://localhost/*"]
}
}
```

Maybe it's the *://localhost/* which I'm using for testing.  But Chrome does not complain.

Any ideas out there?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Err, `// For tests.` is not valid JSON, you cannot have comments inside this file. Try taking that out.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I took it out and no change. Chrome loads the packaged app and runs it OK.  Note that it's not packed.  Unfortunately, my regular web page (from file://localhost/) still has chrome.runtime as undefined.

Comment: From the docs: 'The URL pattern must contain at least a second-level domain - that is, hostname patterns like `"*"`, `"*.com"`, `"*.co.uk"`, and `"*.appspot.com"` are prohibited.' Try defining a second-level alias for 127.0.0.1 in your hosts file and use that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Xan's comment did the trick.

While Chrome did not complain about `*://localhost/*`, it did not work.  Chrome did complain about other combinations such as `file://localhost/`.

I added foo.com to host file and then served up my web page through a web server, and it worked!  I can communicate from my web page to my packaged app.

Note that  browsing to file://www.foo.com/hostpage.html did not work.  But browing to http://www.foo.com:3000/hostpage.html did.  (I'm using Rails, hence the 3000 port).

Morale of the story:  When testing locally, you need to add an entry with a bogus second level domain to your host file.

Here's my manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "RFID Tag Reader",
  "description": "Reads RFID Tags connected via USB reader",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "rfid-16.png",
    "128": "rfid-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "serial",
    "*://www.foo.com/*",
    "*://arealsite.net/*"
  ],
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
      "*://www.foo.com/*",
      "*://arealsite.net/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You could've asked me to convert my comment to an answer.. But oh well. My own fault for answering in the comments.

Comment: Sorry.  I'm not too stack overflow savvy.  If you want to convert it to an answer and then I accept it, that would be just fine with me.

Comment: I did what was suggested but had no luck. How did your manifest ended up looking like? @Crivens

Comment: I tried localhost in externally_connectable, and it actually works

Comment: For those who are new to the host file, just add this entry to `/etc/hosts` on a mac: `127.0.0.1 your-test-domain.com`. If it does not work right away, try clearing your cache. It might be browser related.

Comment: adding `"*://localhost/*"` as a "matches" in "externally_connectable" worked for me too (Chrome 86.0.4240.111)

Answer (score 3):

Adding `"*://localhost/*"` to `externally_connectable` worked for me.